# Что делает этот метод?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, веб-программирование, python-2.x

На просторах форума встретил такой кусок кода, как абстрактный пример. Что такое dispatch, какую полезную нагрузку должна нести функция, как её правильно писать и что есть смежного в этой сфере?

Спасибо

```
@method_decorator(login_required)
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это метод, в который приходит "сырой" `HTTP` пакет.

Именно метод [`dispatch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) отвечает за то, в какой метод далее передать пакет: `GET` в `get`, `POST` в `post` и т. д.

***Код:***

```py
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Try to dispatch to the right method; if a method doesn't exist,
    # defer to the error handler. Also defer to the error handler if the
    # request method isn't on the approved list.
    if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
        handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
    else:
        handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

В Вашем случае, этот метод переопределяют, чтобы сделать доступ к представлению (всем его методам) только залогиненым пользователям с помощью декоратора [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required).

Answer (score 3):

Метод dispatch - это метод, который отвечает за выбор (и вызов) метода обработки запроса:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
    # Try to dispatch to the right method; if a method doesn't exist, 
    # defer to the error handler. Also defer to the error handler if the 
    # request method isn't on the approved list. 
    if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names: 
        handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed) 
    else: 
        handler = self.http_method_not_allowed 
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

В вашем конкретном случае он переопределен только с целью проверки пользователя на авторизацию с помощью декоратора [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator), который в случае, если пользователь не авторизован , переадресовывает его на страницу авторизации.

Адрес для авторизации должен быть задан в  `settings.py`  константой LOGIN_URL.

Comment: Может settings?

Comment: @Qwertiy , да, спасибо. Исправил